# SystemAccentColor + Converter

Tags: xaml, uwp, windows-10-universal

[UWP] I created a *SolidColorBrush* resource from *SystemAccentColor* color, I tried to add a converter to lighten the color but it work only at runtime... I see the color lighter but if I go in the settings OS and I change the accent color, it change in other texts while my color with converter doesn't work. Is there a method to "update" my resource when I change the system accent color?

**In my app:**

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource AuraAccent}"/>
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource AuraAccentLight1}"/>
```

**ResourceDictionary:**

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="AuraAccent" Color="{ThemeResource SystemAccentColor}"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="AuraAccentLight1" Color="{Binding Source={ThemeResource SystemAccentColor}, Converter={ThemeResource shade}, ConverterParameter=30}"/>
```

**AuraAccent** work in runtime and when I change the accent color.

**AuraAccentLight1** work in runtime but doesn't work when I change the accent color.

How actually it work: 
http://sharex.lucapatera.it/uploads/2016-08-31_19-34-32.mp4

Comment: What have you already tried? If you share your (relevant) code in your question, it'll make it easier to provide a useful answer.

Comment: See my linked video to understand

Comment: How are you lightening the color in converter? Can we see that code?

Comment: @AVKNaidu Yes, this is my code (row 13): https://github.com/Lukasss93/Aura.Net/blob/master/Aura.Core/Imaging/ColorHelper.cs

Comment: Are you aware about [light/dark shades available for accent colors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/style/color) - maybe you can try to use them without converter?

Comment: Yes, but when I try to add them, the designer tell me: "resource not found." Very weird and I have the last SDK...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by AVK Naidu, I have resolved in this way:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="AuraAccentLight1" Color="{Binding Color, Source={ThemeResource AuraAccent}, Converter={ThemeResource shade}, ConverterParameter=30}"/>
```

Thanks to everyone

Final result:
http://sharex.lucapatera.it/uploads/2016-09-10_19-33-45.gif

Comment: Nice. Glad I was able to help.

Comment: I'd suggest you add your end app.xaml change that you made to this answer and mark it as an answer so that it will be helpful for others.

Comment: I can't do it. Because: "You can accept your own answer in 22 hours". I'm new on stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 0):

I went through few of the resource dictionary files and noticed that The Dictionary will be loaded when App Initially Loads. The changes for Actual Theme Resource will be updated but not custom Brushes ( In your case AuraAccentLight1 because it uses a converter).

This is what I did. Instead of creating a ResourceDictionary with a Shade colour which works only once, I bound the second Grid to first grid saying when first Grid's colour change, second Grid Colour also should be updated.

So below is my XAML

```
<Grid x:Name="grid" Background="{ThemeResource AuraAccent}"/>
<Grid>
    <Grid.Background>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Background.Color, Converter={StaticResource ColorHelper}, ElementName=grid,ConverterParameter=30}" />
    </Grid.Background>
</Grid>
```

Let me know if this Helps.